# Angularjs : ngRepeat list down all the data from server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I successfully fetch data by using $http get from php server. But I have no idea how to display the data in Table form by using ngRepear because all the data is in few different project. I am going to display all the object of data into different row of a table. The following shows data I got from php server.

[image]

Comment: add this data to a scope variable in your controller and then show in the view using ngrepeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following glimpse of code can give you idea

```js
$scope.retrievedData = [];
//retrieve data from your server
//take the data into above scope variable
```

```html
<table>
<tr ng-repeat = "data in retrievedData">
<td>data.AssetDescription</td>
<td>data.AssetNumber</td>
<td>data.ComputerName</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that data to controller variable:

**Controller**

```
function YourController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.tableData = [];

    $http.get('url').then(function(result) {
         $scope.tableData = result.data;
    });
}
```

**Template**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Computer name</th>
            <th>Borrow date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in tableData ">
            <td>{{row.data.AssetDescription}}</td>
            <td>{{row.data.ComputerName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.data.borrowDate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```